# Ability to show all steps in introJS

Tags: javascript, intro.js

Is it possible to show all of the introJS step numbers at once (not the highlighting their associated elements or toolTips) - so one could see all the areas of the page that have 'explanations'? Then make all of those numbers clickable so that the user could choose to see an explanation on any part of the site (as long an intro step has been set up for that part)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in current version of IntroJs you can't see all steps of introduction at once and it's step-by-step by default but you can create your custom branch for doing this.

All I can say is that I'll work on that in further versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! A follow up question - is there a way to call `introJs().goToStep(N)` while introJS is active, eg. allowing one to jump to a specific step instead of just the next or previous (and without exiting introJS first)?

Comment: @Edragame You can call `goToStep` function ALSO when introduction is active.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Just wondering, if any progress has been made on this? I saw this https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js but has very limited flexibility. If its not possible I might be interested to contribute.